# How can a function in VBA modify the row number of an argument?

Tags: excel, vba, function, cell

I am trying to create a custom function in VBA in Excel. It is my first time.

I want to determine the benefit that a typical person would get (if our government expanded social assistance in response to the covid-19 lockdown), based on data from nine different deciles of the earnings distribution. I have called the function which finds the grant at each decile `onerow`, and the function that averages those `UIFavg`.

In my Excel file, the deciles are listed in a column, so I only want to use the cell at the top as the argument. That would require me to find the row of the `firstrow` argument, then add 1 to the row number for the other nine points. Unfortunately, I don't know how to stipulate the row numbers that the function should use for the various deciles in this way. I didn't know how to search [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/) for this.

I show my attempt below. Do you know how to break lines?

```
Public Function onerow(decile As Double, propzero As Double, propupper As Double, upperbound As Double, natminwage As Double)
    If decile < upperbound Then
        If decile < natminwage Then
            onerow = (propzero - (propzero - propupper) / upperbound * decile) * natminwage       'UIF benefit at the minimum wage
        ElseIf decile >= natminwage Then
            onerow = (propzero - (propzero - propupper) / upperbound * decile) * decile
        End If
    Else
        onerow = propupper * upperbound   'Maximum benefit (for those who earn above the upper limit)
    End If
End Function

Public Function UIFavg(firstrow As Double, secondrow As Double, thirdrow As Double, fourthrow As Double, fifthrow As Double, sixthrow As Double, seventhrow As Double, eighthrow As Double, ninthrow As Double, propzero As Double, propupper As Double, upperbound As Double, natminwage As Double)
UIFavg = (1.5 * onerow(firstrow, propzero, propupper, upperbound, natminwage) + onerow(secondrow, propzero, propupper, upperbound, natminwage) + onerow(thirdrow, propzero, propupper, upperbound, natminwage) + onerow(fourthrow, propzero, propupper, upperbound, natminwage) + onerow(fifthrow, propzero, propupper, upperbound, natminwage) + onerow(sixthrow, propzero, propupper, upperbound, natminwage) + onerow(seventhrow, propzero, propupper, upperbound, natminwage) + onerow(eighthrow, propzero, propupper, upperbound, natminwage) + 1.5 * onerow(ninthrow, propzero, propupper, upperbound, natminwage)) / 10
End Function
```

Comment: Probably better to just pass the function the entire range...

Comment: Using repetitive variable names like `firstrow, secondrow, ...` which have an implicit counter is almost always a bad sign. They should be replaced by a single variable which is an array or (as @BigBen suggests) range. Just how that would look is hard to say since your code seems a bit obscure.

Comment: @JohnColeman how do I call the respective rows from an array?

Comment: I'm not sure how to search the documentation or where to find this in the documentation.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Comment: Perhaps you need to work through a book or tutorial on VBA? It is a fairly easy language to pick up and you seem to be a programmer so you could pick it up even faster than most people. A good day or two on basic VBA before trying to write something like this might save you hours of frustration in the long run.